# How to alias a range of ports to a specific port

Tags: ubuntu, port

I have a service running at port 3000, how can I forward ports [12000 to 14000] (2000 total ports) to the port 3000 with one command.

I don't prefer to manually add each port though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 12000:14000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000`